# Поиск по полю ассоциации

Tags: запрос, sql, ruby-on-rails

Как сделать поисковый запрос по полю ассоциации?

Answer (score 1):

Внезапно нашел ответ в документации:

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight
Client.joins(:orders).where('orders.created_at' => time_range)
```